# How to integrate Marionette.js , Backbone.js and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to use backbone.Marionette to manage the layout of my website.
and now I have a class named layout.js.coffee

```
class Views.Layout extends Marionette.Layout
  template: '#layout-template'
  regions:
    main: '#main-region'
    options: '#integration-options'
```

and I know I should have a template called layout-template.
But where I can place this 'layout-template' file? Refer to the usage of CompositeView of marionette, I normally place the template in the templates folder and in the CompositeView, I can directly use

```
template: 'books/books'
```

So what is the meaning of '#' before the template? What should I name this template?

And if I want to show layout view, should I do something in controller like:

```
...
book.fetch
  success ->
    layout = new Books.Views.Layout
    layout.render()
    MyApp.main.show layout
```

Could anyone help me? I can not find any similar tutorial or example about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is below:

```
LayoutView extends Marionette.LayoutView
  regions:
    main: '#main'
    other: '#other'      
ViewA extends Marionette.CompositeView
ViewB extends Marionette.CompositeView

layoutView = new LayoutView
viewA = new ViewA
viewB = new ViewB

app.main.show layoutView
layoutView.main.show ViewA
layoutView.other.show ViewB
```